# @ManyToOne, Can one column reference to two other Columns?

Tags: java, hibernate

Can I have a relationship as below:

```
@Entity Table1{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Column1", 
                referencedColumnName = "t2id", 
                insertable = false, 
                updatable = false)
    private Table2 table2_col;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Column1", 
                referencedColumnName = "t3id", 
                insertable = false, 
                updatable = false)
    private Table3 table3_col;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mapping looks valid.
The column `Column1` in both cases belong to different tables (`Table2.column1` and `Table3.column1`). So I don't see any collision here. It is not the case as the tittle says "one column references to two other columns".

In this case you have two *many-to-one* relations: **Table1<--->Table2** and  **Table1<--->Table3**. So the **column1** in both tables (2 and 3) is a Foreign Key to the **Table1**. So you have 2 different foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks, but the Column1 is the column of Table1 and it references t2id from Table2 and t2id from Table3, so it is still same as a single column referencing two other columns. Is that a valid scenario? Because I don't get desired output.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Sorry, I misread your code. Can you show the Table2 and Table3 mapping? What exactly are you trying to implement? May be you problem can be solved using different mapping? In terms of database you cannot have a foreign key referencing more than one column. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables). But there are workarounds.

Comment: Btw, it's not a good idea to think tables when working with ORM. Instead it's better to think objects.