# Create table with two references in a foreign key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE Album (
    name          VARCHAR(50),
    lenght    FLOAT,
    genre VARCHAR(30),
    nrSongs INT,

    PRIMARY KEY (name, writer),
    FOREIGN KEY (writer) REFERENCES Musician(name) OR Band(name),
    FOREIGN KEY (Studio) REFERENCES Studio(name)

);
```

Ok this is what I'm trying to do, I have two tables called Musician and Band, and in the foreign key called writer I want to use the name of a Musician or a Band, but this gives me an error in the OR statement, do you know the correct way to implement this? I can't find it.
Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. A foreign key is a direct link between one field in one table, and another field in another table. It is 1:1. You cannot have n:1, 1:n, or n:n mappings in a foreign key definition.

Plus, your overall table definition is invalid. You have no `writer` field, so your primary key and the writer FK will fail anyways.

For this particular purpose, why not just making everyone a "band". A solo artist is simply a band that happens to have one member.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution, but I need the two tables, is there no other option?