# Foreign key reference to a specific subtype

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database, supertype

This question piggybacks off of [Foreign Key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables)
but I thought that my elaboration could use its own subject.

Say I have the following schema (adapted from [@Nathan Skerl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3769/nathan-skerl) answer in the above link):

```
    create table dbo.PartyType
(   
    PartyTypeId tinyint primary key,
    PartyTypeName varchar(10)
)

insert into dbo.PartyType
    values(1, 'User'), (2, 'Group');


create table dbo.Party
(
    PartyId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    PartyTypeid tinyint references dbo.PartyType(PartyTypeId),
    unique (PartyId, PartyTypeId)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Group]
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PartyTypeId as cast(2 as tinyint) persisted,
    foreign key (ID, PartyTypeId) references Party(PartyId, PartyTypeID)
)  

CREATE TABLE dbo.[User]
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PartyTypeId as cast(1 as tinyint) persisted,
    foreign key (ID, PartyTypeId) references Party(PartyID, PartyTypeID)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Ticket
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    [Owner] int NOT NULL references dbo.Party(PartyId),
    [Subject] varchar(50) NULL
)
```

And say I had another relation, say 'Stuff', where 'Users' could possess many items of 'Stuff', but it did not make sense for 'Groups' to have 'Stuff'. Could I have a Foreign Key in 'Stuff' reference just 'User'?

If it is possible, then how would one go about doing so? Or do I have to do all of my foreign keys of that sort directly through 'Party'?
I got an error (*There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Users' that match the referencing column 'ID' in the foreign key*) when I tried myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want.  The idea is to create a unique key on `PartyTypeId, Id`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[User] (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PartyTypeId as cast(1 as tinyint) persisted,
    foreign key (ID, PartyTypeId) references Party(PartyID, PartyTypeID),
    unique (PartyTypeId, Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Stuff (
    StuffId int not null primary key,
    UserId int,
    PartyTypeId as cast(1 as tinyint)  persisted,
    Foreign Key (UserId) references user(PartyTypeId, userId)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2e029) is a SQL Fiddle.
This is explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx).

Comment: Thanks you for the very helpful answer, and the attached links. Helped my understanding too. Couple of things: code above doesn't match the Fiddle; in fact the code above generates a "Number of referencing columns in foreign key differs from number of referenced columns, table 'Stuff'." error.

Comment: Second, I was wondering about the pros/cons of asserting uniqueness on just the ID field in User, and then having the FK in Stuff be just the UserId field (thus dropping the PartyTypeId field)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a foreign key in Stuff reference just User:

```
CREATE TABLE Stuff (
    StuffId int not null primary key,
    UserId int,
    Foreign Key (UserId) references dbo.[User](ID)
);
```