# Foreign key target depends on value of foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have the basic setup depicted in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b21f).  In short, I have a table which has a candidate foreign key whose value may ID a record in one of *several* tables (if it's not NULL, that is)!  How am I supposed to tell Oracle (11g r2) about this, or is putting a foreign key constraint on such a column a hopeless cause?

(Note: this is *not* due to any sort of partitioning -- the equivalents to `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` in the real DB have completely different schemas save for them all having IDs that can be guaranteed to not overlap.)

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to [Foreign Key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables)

That question's top answer proposes many good solutions, but in your case a standard practice you could follow is to have a column for the ids to each of your tables(bar_id, baz_id, and foo_id).