# Foreign keys in databases referencing multiple tables

Tags: sql

Is it possible for a foreign key to reference several tables?

If not, how can we achieve one table linking to several others if not using the foreign key?

If yes, how?

Comment: A single foreign key can only reference two tables. 
However, You can specify multiple foreign keys between multiple tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key to multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question but if you mean two tables will reference a third table it is possible but if you mean connection of many to many between tables then you will have create another table which will hold both foreign keys.

Comment: thanks, i actually found out that you can not use one foreign key to reference more than one other table.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare as foreign keys as you need every one for one table

Answer (score -1):

You can always link any two tables through a join in a query, provided you can devise some boolean expression which defines the relationship.

Comment: another method is to use joins, that worked well, thanks.