# mySQL contact table for person AND company

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `person` and `company`.
I want to create a table `address` knowing that:

- a `person` can have zero, one or several `address`
- a `company` can have zero, one or several `address`
- the basic rows for `address` are the same for `person` and `company`

**Solution 1**

- Create a table `address` (no foreign key) with all address rows (street, city...)
- Create a `person_address` with foreign keys `address_id` and `person_id`
- Create a `company_address` with foreign keys `address_id` and `company_id`

=> A `person` and `company` can share the same address (good) and no duplication (good)
=> A bit cumbersome: I frist have to create `adress` then `person/company_address`

**Solution 2**

- Create a table `person_adress` with foreign key `person_id` **and all address rows**
- Create a table `company_adress` with foreign key `company_id` **and all address rows again**

=> Rows for address info are defined twice

**Solution 3?**

Is there a way to create an **unique table `adress`** which could refer to either a `person` OR a `company`?

Comment: Yes, first thing that pops to mind, you can have your person and company tables as they are, then have a third table with a PK that consists of entity_id, a column entity_type (PERSON/COMPANY/ETC), and a col for the address. You can enforce the relationship programmatically with a combo of id/type. Other options as well.

Comment: Thank you. But in this case, can the entity_id be a foreign key? If it refers to a PERSON and PERSON_ID changes, is there a way to cascade the change to ADRESS?

Comment: This guys goes into other options. #4 is the best. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables

Comment: I would be tempted to force all people to belong to (at least) one organisation - even if that organisation was rather artificial, e.g. 'Bob's house'

Comment: @JacobBarnes Thanks, I'll look into that!

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, tempted too, at first. OR consider that organisations have at least one employee who works at an address. But I want to be able to list all companies and not have Bob's House in them.

Comment: @JacobBarnes Looks exactly like my issue. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You could have a flag that identified real and fictitious organisations

Comment: Yes, that would work. But the idea of a parent table works better for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jacob Barnes for the link:
[Foreign Key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables)

Create a "parent table" `entity` which can either be a `person` or a `company`. `adress` then refers to `entity`.