# SQL Data models

Tags: sql, database

Can someone help me out with this task (I didn't get it)?

[image: Data Model]

Comment: it's not a homework, it's something i need right now (i'm not asking for answers just hints about Q.1.2 )

Comment: This sounds like you have to create a [Foreign Key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7844460/8097737)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 1.2 you will need one more table which will hold task and items relation ship for example

```
Table : Task_Item_Rel {TaskID,ItemID}
```

whenver you want item related to a particular task simply have a query with joins between task,item and Task_Item_Rel