# SQL - can a table column in a foreign key relation reference to two different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl

current situation:

I have a table **A** which has a column. This column should have a foreign key relationship to either **C** or **D**

How can I describe this in SQL Definition Language

**To be more clear:**

C and D are e.g. tables with information about Taxes. But this taxes are not in one table. They are distributed in this two tables.

What I now want ist that the **Foreign Key Referenc**e in table A should have a Foreign Key reference at the same time on the same column e.g. A->**tax_rate_id** to either Table C or D.

Is this possible and how to write the DDL description for it

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. Eg google your current title. PS Google re database/SQL subtyping/poymorphism/hierarchies for how to avoid this antipattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key cannot have reference to 2 tables at once. You should read the definition of foreign keys.

Comment: Hi, @amin I tried to update the description of the question

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, "FK" has a definition & it means a certain thing & one has one target. But what does "this isn't even possible in real world" mean? A column set sure can be constrained to have a value in one target or (exclusively or inclusively) another. It's just not a FK constraint.

Comment: Yes you're right. We have, but I think it's rare for them to be primary in both tables. Anyway answer edited.