# FK Reference multiple tables. Database relations and foreign key constraints in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a "Files" table (id, Name, Path, Owner). I want to link the Owner column to multiple tables (students, supervisors ...). For example the owner of a file could be a student, supervisor or Evaluating committee. What is the efficient solution to this problem since I can not reference a foreign key to multiple tables?

Comment: You could have separate connecting tables for each possible owner, or restructure you database so that student, supervisor, and committee tables are all in one "users" table (and differentiated by a user type field); with optional student_details, staff_details, and/or committee_details tables for information unique to the different types.

Comment: This might be a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables

Answer (score 0):

You are best using a polymorphic relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Alternatively you could have a users table and have different roles for users using something like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission