# how to reference concrete inheritance with TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

From TypeORM's documentation they describe Concrete table inheritance with the following example:

```js
export abstract class Content {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
 
    @Column()
    title: string;
    
    @Column()
    description: string;
    
}
@Entity()
export class Photo extends Content {
    
    @Column()
    size: string;
    
}
@Entity()
export class Question extends Content {
    
    @Column()
    answersCount: number;
    
}
@Entity()
export class Post extends Content {
    
    @Column()
    viewCount: number;
    
}
```

My question is if you want to add a relation to the abstract class.  SO ....

```js
export abstract class Content {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    description: string;

    // WOULD LIKE TO ADD SOMETHING LIKE THIS ...
    @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.createdContent)
    createdBy: User

}


@Entity()
export default class User {

  // AND THIS ...
  @OneToMany(() => Content, content => content.authoredBy)
  authoredContent: Content[]

}
```

Is there a possible solution to make this possible.  NOTE:  You can achieve this with Single Table Inheritance

Comment: I'm trying to implement something similar - did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely impossible by design, since in a SQL database, you can't have a foreign key that references multiple different tables at once (without some very non-standard shenanigans).

*Single table inheritance* is your best bet in my opinion, because all the variants are stored in a single table. You can also read through this thread for more reference: [Foreign Key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables)