# Multiple relations from many entities to one entitiy in SQL Server (EF core)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Can anybody help me? I want to set constraint to my database for example:

- First entity is `Triangle` (Triangle_Id, Name, Side_size)
- Second entity is `Square` (Square_Id, Name, Side_size)
- Third entity is `Area` (Area_Id, ObjectId, Area_value)
- Fourth entity is `Circle` (Circle_Id, Name, Radius)

How can I add constraints from entities `Triangle` and `Square` to `Area` that I am unable to write any other type of objects in `ObjectId` column except triangle or square?

I tried to write come FK constraints, but have had an error.

- FK_Area_Triangle_ObjectId (area_ObjectId == triangle_Id)
- FK_Area_Square_ObjectId (area_ObjectId == square_Id)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two different foreign key constraints on same column, but there are some options as answered here: [Foreign Key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables).

1. You could simply create two columns in Area, SquareId and TriangleId, and have nullable Foreign Keys to each table. You can also add a constraint, that exactly one of these two columns has to be filled.
2. Model an entity that acts as a base for both Square and Triangle, and have Area refer to that entity

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but in future, there will be more than 10 entities, and your solution doesn't fit well for me. The example was simplified, the real table has a lot of entities and common values, that's why I'm looking for a method to store only existing values in common table using ObjectId as key.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key is defined between two tables. It cannot be made between a table and a view, which would solve your task directly.

What you can do, if to create a scalar function checking for records in both tables and returning 1 if found and 0, if not. And then put a constraint that the function should be 1.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but your solution doesn't fit well for me. But your answer helped me to find one more problem in my solution (connected with transactions). Thanks a lot!