# Foreign Key References Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm currently working on a database and I came across a new problem to me. The entities involved are Universe, Competition, Game, Pot. Here are the SQL files to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Universe (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    history nvarchar (max),
    creation_date date
);

CREATE TABLE Pot (
    pot_name nvarchar(100),
    universe_id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Universe(id),
    pot_description nvarchar(100),
    media_description nvarchar(100),
    is_official_pot bit
    PRIMARY KEY (pot_name, universe_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Competition (
    universe_id int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Universe(id),
    compt_name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    alias nvarchar(100),
    history nvarchar(max),
    rules nvarchar (max),
    winner_id nvarchar(100) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES RaulUser(username),
    edition int NOT NULL,
    is_official_competition bit NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (universe_id, compt_name, edition)
);

CREATE TABLE Game (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    pot_name nvarchar (100) NOT NULL,
    universe_id int NOT NULL,
    competition_name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    competition_edition int NOT NULL,
    competition_round int NOT NULL,
    home_raul_u_username nvarchar (100) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES RaulUser(username) NOT NULL,
    home_team nvarchar (100) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Team(team_name),
    home_score  int,
    away_raul_u_username nvarchar (100) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES RaulUser(username),
    away_team nvarchar (100) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Team(team_name),
    away_score  int,
    is_over bit NOT NULL,
    played_date date,
    FOREIGN KEY (universe_id, competition_name, competition_edition) REFERENCES Competition(universe_id, compt_name, edition),
    FOREIGN KEY (universe_id, pot_name) REFERENCES Pot(universe_id, pot_name)
);
```

The problem starts with this last table (Game), as I can't use universe_id as a Foreign Key for different tables. What's the best approach to solving this? Creating an M:M table Game_Pot?
I only need to record the Pot of each Game because Pots change overtime and I don't want to lose that data.

Sorry for the long post and thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables

Comment: MySQL does not support `IDENTITY`. Maybe you are running SQL Server?

Comment: @Will thank you for the link! I had already checked that post but it addresses a different aspect. In that case, the Foreign key that references Multiple Tables can EITHER be referring on or the other. In my case it is always referring both tables.

Comment: @GMB I'm running a SQL Server, yes, and managing it with MSSMS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that I see is in the definition of table `Game`:

```
FOREIGN KEY (universe_id, pot_name) REFERENCES Pot(universe_id, pot_name)
```

Ordering of columns matters. The primary key of table `Pot` is `(pot_name, universe_id)`, so you need to swap the columns in the foreign key, like so:

```
FOREIGN KEY (pot_name, universe_id) REFERENCES Pot(pot_name, universe_id)
```

Note that having `identity` (or the-like) primary key in every table might simplify your design: it would allow you to reduce the number of columns in the children tables, and to use single-column foreign keys. Meanwhile, you can still enforce uniqeness on columns tuples in the parent tables with unique constraints.

Comment: Thank you so much :) The problem was about the Ordering like you said. I didn't know it is important! Lesson learned!
Regarding the use of an Id: shouldn't I avoid using an ID when I have a natural key, although composed? In some other tables, I do use IDs but I try to reduce its use to those cases where it is absolutely needed. Where can I learn more about this?